# Is smoking battleships worthless?

Tags: world-of-warships

1. As a DD player, other DDs and CAs ask me to smoke-screen them, but never BBs. Whenever I proffer smoke to BBs player, they always decline and say that smoke for them is useless. But why? Is it worthless to smoke BBs?
2. If not, when ought BBs be smoked?

On [Smoke Screens - Global wiki. Wargaming.net](https://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Ship:Smoke_Screens),  the only sentence that looks germane is

> Firing while in smoke increases the detection of a ship. While not firing, all ships are subject to a 2.0km detection radius, and will not be seen without the use of [Surveillance Radar](https://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Surveillance_Radar) ([image: While active, detects all enemy ships within the specified radius, disregarding obstacles such as smoke and terrain.]) or [Hydroacoustic Search](https://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Hydroacoustic_Search) ([image: While active, detects all enemy ships and torpedoes within the specified radius, without regard of obstacles such as smoke and terrain.]). However, upon firing, a ship's detection will increase based on the caliber of its guns. For instance, low tier destroyers do not get any penalty, as their guns are too small. Yamato has a 20km penalty.

Answer (score 3):

> As a DD player, other DDs and CAs ask me to smoke-screen them, but never BBs. Whenever I proffer smoke to BBs player, they always decline and say that smoke for them is useless. But why? Is it worthless to smoke BBs?

Like what you said, *most* of the time it is worthless to smoke BBs since their gun penalty range doesn't let them hide in smoke.

> If not, when ought BBs be smoked?

Though it is useless *most* of the time, it would be useful in this scenario: 
Smoke BBs that are dying to let them hide in the smoke and heal up with their repair party.
(Of course, tell them to stop firing in the smoke and heal up.)